# pallet storage migration fails try-runtime idempotent test

Tags: try-runtime, storage-migration

Some of the pallets storage migrations fail the idempotent test because in the pre_upgrade method there is an ensure! check to make sure that the current storage version is the one that applies for the migration, even if the actual on_runtime_upgrade does not fail if the storage has already been upgraded. So is it bad practice to perform this kind of ensure! checks in the pre_upgrade method? Ex. [The assets pallet migration performs this type of check.](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/release-polkadot-v1.3.0/substrate/frame/assets/src/migration.rs#L100)

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

There is a new pattern where migrations do not need to check the pre- and post-version anymore. Doing this manually is error-prone, hence there is now a [`VersionedMigration`](https://docs.rs/frame-support/latest/frame_support/migrations/struct.VersionedMigration.html) wrapper that can be used lik:

```rust
pub type MigrationV1ToV2<T> = frame_support::migrations::VersionedMigration<
    1,
    2,
    UncheckedMigrationV1ToV2<T>,
    Pallet<T>,
    <T as frame_system::Config>::DbWeight,
>;
```

The actual migration is in the `UncheckedMigrationToV2`, which now does not need to do any version checks since the versions are passed as const generics to the wrapper. This simplifies the code and removes copy&paste overhead.

Comment: This issue typically arises when a new pallet is added to the runtime without properly setting its version. Sometimes the pallet author forgot to update the pallet version after adding a migration.

Comment: There should also be a check in place now to prevent this when the `try-runtime-cli` is used. It errors and reports that some pallet version must be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

> even if the actual on_runtime_upgrade does not fail if the storage has already been upgraded

*But I want to ask.
Why do you need this migration if you have already upgraded the storage?
Simply remove this migration from your runtime `Executive` and the try runtime will ignore it.*

---

I came across this issue this morning.

I think Substrate does not currently have any adaptations for the new feature of idempotency testing. (please correct me if I'm mistaken)

Here's what I did: https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/pull/1321/commits/c15b4a3c0878c8930f097b7214b6e3af2e88ea83.

Simply change the `ensure!` to `log::warn!`.

Comment: The try-runtime tool runs the migration twice to check for idempotent test, the upgrade has not yet been applied on my runtime

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The issue here is that the pallets with the issue are frame pallets, which I don't want to modify, but I guess is not much of an issue as long as you know what is causing the issue